# Color row based on cells value - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been trying to figure out how to do this. For some reason when I use the ".yellow" selector, it returns an object, but I cannot get to the parent of the object, keeps saying everything about it is null.

I have this cell:

```
<td aria-describedby="CommodityControlReportGrid_ApprovalType" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">
    <span class="yellow"></span>
    Ignored
</td>
```

The parent row of these different cells all have the following schema:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" id="101023" role="row"></tr>
```

Basically, I want to apply a background color of the row based on the rows that contain the cell with a `<span class="yellow"></span>`.

How would I do this in Jquery, or at least select the row I want (I know how to apply the color)?

Comment: why not add `yellow` to the parent?

Comment: We're using a server side grid framework that only allows us to modify cells, not their parent rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select by the span with class yellow - gets them all.. then apply to the corresponding tr

```
$('span.yellow').closest('tr').css('background-color','yellow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtY7Q/

Comment: .closest will traverse up it's ancestors until it finds the element or return nothing :).. just like parent except it doesn't stop one level up

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that even if you only have one span with class yellow, selecting by the non-unique class will return an array. Be sure to either access an element directly, or loop over each returned item:

```
$('span.yellow').each(function(){alert(1);$(this).parents().closest('tr').attr('style','background-color:yellow')});​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

check this may it's helpful

JsFiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HTh9L/5/)

```
   var1 = $("td").children('span').attr('class');
    $("td").css("background-color",var1);
```

​